# Как сделать переход на другой фрагмент из Меню

Tags: android, android-fragment

Приложение крашится, шаблон Navigation Drawer.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.refresh_page:
            Fragment frag = null;
            mWebView.reload();
            //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Обновить", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        case R.id.back_page:

            if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                mWebView.goBack();
                //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Назад", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;


        case R.id.snd_msg_support:
            fragment = new BtnSndSupportFragment();
            break;


    }

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.btnsndsupport, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Ошибка: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a004a for fragment BtnSndSupportFragment{586bb71 (29d81b19-06d0-4693-a587-f17bf2a409d2) id=0x7f0a004a}`

---

Разметка Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow, R.id.nav_salles, R.id.btnsndsupport)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);


}


@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

Activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />



</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coord"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/content_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Скорее всего вам надо заменить R.id.btnsndsupport на id контейнера для фрагментов в разметке активити

Comment: Пробовал, та же самая ошибка вылетает. Только уже с другим кодом

Comment: Покажите разметку активити и покажите что конкретно  ещё вы пробовали

Comment: Отправил разметку

Comment: Это не разметка, это код. Вам надо `activity_main.xml` показать. И надо для этого вопрос править, а не ответ писать. Править можно так: [правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1174696/edit)

Comment: Да, отредактировал ниже добавил разметку activity_main.xml

Comment: Тут нужного нет. Добавьте ещё файл `app_bar_main.xml` - возможно там то, что нужно

Comment: Все добавил разметку app_bar_main

Comment: Это тоже не то. Видимо в `content_main` нужный  ID искать надо.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, действительно при указании разметки из content_mein, когда указал id, работает.